# How to compile objc(c++, c) source on jailbroken iPad?

Tags: ipad, gcc, compilation, jailbreak

I've installed gcc but when I execute this comand:

`gcc test.c`

It says me:

`test.c:1:18: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory`

```
test.c: In function 'main':

test.c:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of builit-in function 'printf'
```

Test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well i just did the same, but you need to copy the header files into the ipad /usr/include via SSH but after that i keep getting other errors so there must be another step after copying the headers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `-I/var/include`. iphone-gcc fails to notice that most of the main headers needed are under that folder and search on other directory that you can see with `gcc -v test.c`.
Try this way or copy all the headers and libraries from an SDK (preferably from the same of the iOS version you have) to /usr/include and /usr/lib.
You'll still need the Frameworks under /Library/Frameworks or you'll have to add the location they are via `-F/path/to/framework/from/sdk`